# Why does 7/N equal 7 for this Riemann Sum Question.

Tags: calculus

Why does the Riemann sum of 7/N equal seven in this example?

I thought we just had to divide the N by infinity which would end up just equaling 0.

[image: PART 1]

[image: PART 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the limit you are referring to, 7/N is to be multiplied N times as summed over N, therefore it comes lim(N*(7/N)) =lim(7) =7

EDIT: I doubt this is what puzzles you but just in case, maybe it can be helpful to stress that this is sum of the terms 7/N and not the sum of 7/i

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

That's because $$\sum_{i=1}^N\frac7N=\frac7N\sum_{i=1}^N\, 1=\frac7N\cdot N=7.$$

Comment: Indeed: it is not to be confused with $\displaystyle\sum_{i}^N\frac{7}{i}$ which results in something completely different